# Est-ce que la phrase "Les objets sont des composants avec un certain nombre de fonctionnalité" est écrite correctement ?

Tags: pluriel, accord

J'aimerai savoir si cette phrase est correct grammaticalement.

> Les objets sont des composants avec un certain nombre de fonctionnalité.

Y'a-t-il un **s** manquant dans la partie **un certain nombre de fonctionnalité** ?
c'est quoi le principe général ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il manque effectivement un **s** à **fonctionnalités**.

Étant donné que l'on parle d'**un certain nombre**, on sous-entend que les objets disposent de plusieurs fonctionnalités. D'où l'usage du pluriel.